# Why am i getting a String in laravel method when i am actually passing a array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following line of code in my view file in laravel::

```
<a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , ['data' => Session::get('quality-data')]) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
```

The following route is setup in my routes file:

```
Route::get('showQualityResult/{data}', [
    'as' => 'showQualityResult', 
    'uses' => 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult'
]);
```

When clicked on the a tag the folling controller emthod is run:

```
public function showQualityResult($qualityData) {
        return $qualityData;
}
```

As of now i get the following string in my view:

```
45
```

Why am i getting this string/Number ?? When clearly i am passing an array in the route method used as following:

```
<a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , ['data' => Session::get('quality-data')]) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
```

Can somebody elaborate and explain this to me please as i am a bit suprised as of now with the result that i am getting.

Comment: The way you try to pass data is wrong, you should do this inside a form and on submit trigger the proper route. Another way to go will be to send the data as http arguments and use the `Request` class to get all inputs. like so: `<a href="/show-quality-results?data={{ Session::get('quality-data') }}">click me</a>`. Than inside your method do `function showQualityResult (Request $request){  return $request->all() }`. this $request->all() will output an array of all the parameters you passed in the URL.

Comment: @AfikDeri that does look a bit ugly ... is there any other option ??

Comment: Create a form with hidden inputs for your required data and change the <a> tag to a submit button . On your controller method use the Request again to use the data. This is the cleanest way to go!!

Comment: While both of the above work, a cleaner solution is to use the jQuery library to execute GET/POST requests and just fire a function onclick of the <a> tag. Passing in the necessary information as a parameter would work. Nothing really "wrong" about the above, and this is only if you can get by with jQuery (or another library). Simply a suggestion. You can then have the server respond with information, and update the UI accordingly. To make it more real-time if you will.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to the `route()` method expects an array of parameters to send to the route. It loops through the array you pass in and replaces route parameters with the values specified in the array.

So, in this case, you've specified there is one parameter, named `data`, and it has the value of `Session::get('quality-data')` (which, I'm assuming is `45`), so it takes your route definition `showQualityResult/{data}` and creates the actual route of `showQualityResult/45`.